# Font file parsing error with GWT (2.8.0) on LibGDX 1.9.5

Tags: gwt, libgdx

I wonder if I am doing something wrong, or if I have stumbled upon a bug in LibGDX/GWT. I have a game with desktop/Android/iOS/HTML backends and upgrading to 1.9.5 from 1.9.5-SNAPSHOT from about a month ago made the HTML build stop working. The main change I can see is the upgrade to GWT 2.8.0 from 2.6.0.

When I run my app in a browser (Chrome 56.0.2924.21 beta (64-bit) on Windows 10), I get the following error:

```
GwtApplication: exception: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: static/uiskin_hd.json
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: static/uiskin_hd.json
Error reading file: static/uiskin_hd.json
Error reading file: static/uiskin_hd.json
Error loading bitmap font: static/helsinki28plain_hd.fnt
Error loading font file: static/helsinki28plain_hd.fnt
Invalid page id: 
For input string: ""
```

The font has been working previously and I get the same result with any font, including default.fnt from LibGDX tests. The top of the font file looks like this:

```
info face="Helsinki" size=56 bold=0 italic=0 charset="" unicode=0 stretchH=100 smooth=1 aa=1 padding=2,2,8,4 spacing=0,0
common lineHeight=75 base=52 scaleW=512 scaleH=1024 pages=1 packed=0
page id=0 file="helsinki28plain_hd.png"
chars count=141
char id=32   x=0     y=0     width=0     height=0     xoffset=0     yoffset=52    xadvance=22     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=92   x=0     y=0     width=24     height=72     xoffset=-2     yoffset=0    xadvance=22     page=0  chnl=0 
char id=47   x=24     y=0     width=24     height=72     xoffset=-2     yoffset=0    xadvance=22     page=0  chnl=0 
...
```

Just to make sure the problem isn't with my setup, I checked out the latest master branch of LibGDX and tried to run the GWT tests:

```
git clone https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx.git
cd libgdx
ant -f fetch
ant
./gradlew tests:gdx-tests-gwt:draftRun
```

This also seems to fail:

```
Compiling module com.badlogic.gdx.tests.gwt.GdxTestsGwt
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devtools/libgdx/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.java'
         [ERROR] Line 80: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devtools/libgdx/backends/gdx-backends-gwt/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/GwtNet.java'
         [ERROR] Line 70: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devtools/libgdx/backends/gdx-backends-gwt/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/preloader/Preloader.java'
         [ERROR] Line 200: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 203: No source code is available for type java.io.ByteArrayInputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devtools/libgdx/backends/gdx-backends-gwt/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/emu/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.java'
         [ERROR] Line 78: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devtools/libgdx/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/net/Socket.java'
         [ERROR] Line 41: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devtools/libgdx/backends/gdx-backends-gwt/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/preloader/Blob.java'
         [ERROR] Line 38: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devtools/libgdx/backends/gdx-backends-gwt/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/emu/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java'
         [ERROR] Line 19: No source code is available for type java.io.FilterInputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 20: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devtools/libgdx/backends/gdx-backends-gwt/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/emu/java/io/Reader.java'
         [ERROR] Line 33: No source code is available for type java.io.Closeable; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devtools/libgdx/backends/gdx-backends-gwt/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/emu/java/io/Writer.java'
         [ERROR] Line 30: No source code is available for type java.io.Closeable; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 30: No source code is available for type java.io.Flushable; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.badlogic.gdx.tests.gwt.client.GwtTestStarter'
         [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
         [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
:tests:gdx-tests-gwt:draftCompileGwt FAILED
```

Any ideas what is going on here? (My Java SDK is jdk1.8.0_20)

Comment: The parsing error might just happen because the file can't be found by the libgdx runtime. Given that the preloader makes files available to JS in a synchronous way seems to suggest that the trouble to find the io classes might be the root cause for your problem. When something doesn't work the first thing the gwt people typically suggest is to do some kind of clean build. Maybe there is some leftover stuff from the previous version in the way?

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. Based on the error output, the skin json gets loaded correctly as it knows to try to load the font named helsinki28plain_hd. I also tried cleaning everything (under the build directory--I am assuming this is where gradle puts all intermediate work products), but the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in LibGDX 1.9.5. A couple of people have submitted pull requests to fix it, so I expect there will shortly be a 1.9.6-SNAPSHOT available fixing this issue.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/4475

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/4467